# Microsoft Access table, concurrent if statement says syntax error, unable to find one

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm trying to get the square feet of flooring based on the width that the user inputs.

I've tried the following expression:

```
IIf([Width]=1,[total]*2.25/144,IIf([Width]=2,[total]*3/144,IIf([Width]=3,[total]*3.25/144,IIf([Width]=4,[total]*4/144,IIf([Width]=5,[total]*5/144)))))
```

However, I receive the error:

> Syntax error in expression

Answer (score 0):

Your current expression looks to be syntactically correct, and so I suspect that the error originates elsewhere in your query.

However, for your example, a [`choose`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/choose-function-76230415-910f-463a-a799-cf7e90aa7fd4) statement may be more appropriate than multiple nested [`iif`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ECF-C629-48A3-9900-647539C764E3) statements. For example, the following expression will yield the same result:

```
Choose([width],2.25,2,3,3.25,4,5)*[total]/144
```